# Logging client side JS errors inside AJAX content with JSlogger.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, logging

So we're using JSLogger.com with much success on individual pages.  But we have a wizard-type site with about 12 steps in it that all runs on index.asp which is just the CSS and empty container.  It is using jQuery to load each next step progressively as they go through the wizard.

My question is about JS errors -- specifically how we can trap for an log errors occurring within the AJAX pages that are loaded from the server inside the div on index.asp, since index.asp is not actually refreshing ever.  We are using `jQuery.load()` by the way with a POST to fetch the next page.

At this time JSLogger.com only records the error on index.asp so we truly have no idea which inner step of the wizard the error is generated on.  Furthermore, it [JSLogger] gives a hugely bogus line number since the error is bubbling up (so to speak) from the ajax content in the div to the main DOM at index.asp.

Which in all means the JSLogger is not working at all for us shy of letting us know something is wrong but we have no idea where or on which page.

If you have suggestions for alternate JS loggers that work better with AJAX content I'm all ears.

Here is very loosely how our code is laid out...

#### index.asp

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//jslogger.com/jslogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jslogger = new JSLogger();</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#content').load('ajaxcontent.html');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### ajaxcontent.html

```
<html>
<body>
I am some content.
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.getElementById('foo');    // not present in the DOM
var b = a.trim().value();                  // will error
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

By this layout index.asp contains an empty div which is loaded with jQuery.  The ajax content however contains the JS error, which is not being reported correctly as coming from `ajaxcontent.html`, nor the correct line number.

Help!  And thank you very much....

Comment: If your scripts where external js files, would the logger then be able to present a useful line number?

Comment: Kevin, good call -- I'll check on that and report back my findings.

Comment: Keep in mind that ajax loading html with inline js vs html with external js may behave differently.